# Cloudconnect CSV buffer size

Tags: csv, etl, gooddata, cloud-connect

When I try to load a big CSV from a zip file, the execution log give me the following error:

```
----------------------------------------- Error details ------------------------------------------
  Component [Clientes:CLIENTES1] finished with status ERROR.
   The size of data buffer is only 100663296. Set appropriate parameter in defaultProperties file.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I set the appropriate parameter in defaultProperties file?

I tried this [link](https://developer.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/cloudconnect-default-settings.html), but my cloudconnect run configurations page is different from the link:[image]

I've created the parameters file and filled the additional parameters with the right values like said the tutorial (code bellow) and the same error appear in the screen.

```
Name: -config; Value: new_buffer_size.txt
```

The new_buffer_size.txt content have just this line:`DEFAULT_INTERNAL_IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 200000000`

How can I solve this problem? I need to solve this before the world explodes.

Answer (score 1):

CloudConnect is designed to develop ETL(s), which can be run on GoodData cloud workers and therefore some lower level settings are surpassed as in this case. The only legitimate way is to modify the ETL the way it can process the data with current settings. Regarding to docs, the referenced article is outdated. GoodData docs team is aware if it and they are preparing docs refactoring.

Note: As you have probably noticed, CloudConnect is being powered by Javlin's Clover ETL, therefore feel free to check their forums, as you would find there how to overcome the issue on lower level (no UI), but it would work only for data processing on the local machine.